# How to change pages in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

my code is like this :

```
<div data-role="page" id="LoginPage">

    <div data-role="header">

    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <input type="button" value="התחבר" onclick="checkDetails()" />
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">

    </div>
</div>
```

now, by the function checkDetail() i need to move to anthor page(below)

```
<div data-role="page" id="HomePage">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h3>asd</h3>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" class="ui-content">

    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <ul>
            <li><a>a</a></li>
            <li><a>as</a></li>
            <li><a>asd</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

the problem is when i move to it, i reach to HomePage but it shown as a normal html page not a jquery mobile.
By the way, LoginPage shown as jQueryMobile, but HomePage isn't.

That's how i move,

```
$('#LoginPage').hide(function () {
    $('#HomePage').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the `$.show()` and `$.hide()` methods from the core jQuery library for page navigation. Page navigation in jQuery Mobile is handled through the [Pagecontainer Widget](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/) -- specifically using `change` method.

In your example, you would do the following:

```
var homePage = $("#HomePage");
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change",homePage,{});
```

Comment: I saw in a number of videos, and works simply,
not as you said, by the way i opened the page but not a design of mobile

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding. If you are saying that you saw a video which told you to use `.show()` and `.hide()` to open jQuery Mobile pages, then that video is wrong. You need to use the Pagecontainer widget. Please see the duplicate question linked by Omar for the same answer.